# ConvertView not providing expected result

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm passing my images resource to use `AsyncTask` and from there updating my imagesource so that I could get only one image in my listview at a time.

I'm getting expected result without using convertView but when I'm trying to use convertview the result is not as per my wish. Please help me. Below is the code for both cases:

1. without convertView `getView()` method:

   ```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       if (images[position] != null)
           imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
       return imageView;
   }
   ```
2. with convertView `getview()` method:

   ```
   View v = convertView;
       if (v == null) {
           v = new ImageView(context);
           v.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       }
       if (images[position] != null)
           ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(images[position]);
       return v;
   }
   ```

Comment: What result are you getting..?

Comment: finally displayed images are same for both the cases. But intermediate result is different. The first displayed image is displying till the end and i.e vanished at last.

Comment: Try pasting your Asynctask implementation in Edit section. The code snippet you have provided is insufficient to guess what may be causing the problem.

Comment: before return view, initialize convert view with v; like this 
convertView=v; 
return v;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send async task code as well, on the other side,
try this, this works for me-

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.imageView = new ImageView(context);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

             if (images[position] != null)
            ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(images[position]);

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
        }
```